# Uninstall IntelliJ idea from Ubuntu

Tags: server, delete, software-uninstall, intellij, linux-headers

I have **deleted** all files of IntelliJ-idea community edition from my laptop, and when I search on terminal for delete, it shows **not installed**, but on my laptop it is available, help me to delete the IntelliJ idea completely.

[image: Ubuntu menu]

How can I remove the **IntelliJ-idea** from here?

[image: privacy policy]

I have **deleted** all files of Jetbrains then Why I am getting this page i.e. **Jetbrains privacy policy**.

Comment: Not sure exactly which one you installed, but there are 3 snap versions.  `sudo snap remove intellij-idea-community` or `sudo snap remove intellij-idea-ultimate` or `sudo snap remove intellij-idea-educational`

Comment: IntelliJ idea community edition it is**

Comment: You might have to install it again, `sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic` and then remove it `sudo snap remove intellij-idea-community` to get rid of the icon.

Comment: I have deleted that desktop image. 2nd issue, please see my post again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it with the following command:

```
sudo snap remove intellij-idea-community
```

Comment: Thanks @Sibi Saravanan ,  I have tried this, it says, IntelliJ idea  not installed  but see the image attached in my post, intelliJ idea is still there

Comment: Try running this command `sudo apt-get autoremove`, this will clear out junk files of uninstalled apps completely. If again the icon doesn't clear, Then go to `/usr/share/applications` and delete the file of **intellij** that ends with **.desktop**

Comment: I am unable to delete "jetbrains-idea.desktop" this file, can you help me with this too

Comment: Try `sudo rm -rf jetbrains-idea.desktop` If not can you specify what error you are getting while trying to delete?

Comment: hey, one more problem is there, I have deleted this, then I tried to open it using "idea ."  it open again with its agreement page. I am sharing the snapshot in my post

Comment: Ok, Try checking these following locations and remove jetbrains related files if any.   `~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3`  
`~/.local/share/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3`  
`~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3`  
`~/.java/.userPrefs/jetBrains`

Comment: it is saying, NO such directory or file

Comment: I deleted those files, but when I run "idea ." in my terminal, those files get generated again  automatically

Comment: Ok. Lets try removing PPA entry if any. Type `apt policy` and see if any entry related to jetbrains. note down the repo name and  `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:PPA_REPOSITORY_NAME/PPA` , for example `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mmk2410/intellij-idea-community`

Comment: There is nothing related to JetBrains

Comment: Try `umake -r ide idea` and  `umake -r ide idea-ultimate`

Comment: I have tried this, it is giving an error : ERROR: You can't remove Idea as it isn't installed

Comment: So I guess there is no issue with idea anymore. I think its showing up from cache or something. So you may better ignore it and move forward.